# I had 2G of RAM and I upgraded to 6G and it only sees 3G

Tags: ram

I did some searching, and I have a processor that supports `pae`. It is red when I run `cat /proc/cpuinfo | grep pae`

I do have the 64 bit server version installed, however, I'm using a desktop. (That is just how I roll.)

When I started the computer, the boot screen sees the total 6G, so I think my motherboard supports it.

When I run `free -m`, I get a total of `3259`. Also, I don't have an onboard video card. I read somewhere that sometimes to goes to that card.

```
uname -a #33~precise1-Ubuntu SMP the time x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Let me know if you have any suggestions. I'm new to Linux and a bit lost.

```
# dmidecode 2.11
SMBIOS 2.5 present.

Handle 0x0005, DMI type 5, 24 bytes
Memory Controller Information
    Error Detecting Method: 8-bit Parity
    Error Correcting Capabilities:
        None
    Supported Interleave: One-way Interleave
    Current Interleave: One-way Interleave
    Maximum Memory Module Size: 2048 MB
    Maximum Total Memory Size: 8192 MB
    Supported Speeds:
        Other
    Supported Memory Types:
        DIMM
    Memory Module Voltage: 5.0 V
    Associated Memory Slots: 4
        0x0006
        0x0007
        0x0008
        0x0009
    Enabled Error Correcting Capabilities:
        None

Handle 0x0006, DMI type 6, 12 bytes
Memory Module Information
    Socket Designation: DIMM1
    Bank Connections: 0 1
    Current Speed: Unknown
    Type: DIMM
    Installed Size: 1024 MB (Double-bank Connection)
    Enabled Size: 1024 MB (Double-bank Connection)
    Error Status: OK

Handle 0x0007, DMI type 6, 12 bytes
Memory Module Information
    Socket Designation: DIMM2
    Bank Connections: 2 3
    Current Speed: Unknown
    Type: DIMM
    Installed Size: 2048 MB (Double-bank Connection)
    Enabled Size: 2048 MB (Double-bank Connection)
    Error Status: OK

Handle 0x0008, DMI type 6, 12 bytes
Memory Module Information
    Socket Designation: DIMM3
    Bank Connections: 4 5
    Current Speed: Unknown
    Type: DIMM
    Installed Size: 1024 MB (Double-bank Connection)
    Enabled Size: 1024 MB (Double-bank Connection)
    Error Status: OK

Handle 0x0009, DMI type 6, 12 bytes
Memory Module Information
    Socket Designation: DIMM4
    Bank Connections: 6 7
    Current Speed: Unknown
    Type: DIMM
    Installed Size: 2048 MB (Double-bank Connection)
    Enabled Size: 2048 MB (Double-bank Connection)
    Error Status: OK

Handle 0x0024, DMI type 16, 15 bytes
Physical Memory Array
    Location: System Board Or Motherboard
    Use: System Memory
    Error Correction Type: None
    **Maximum Capacity: 4 GB**
    Error Information Handle: Not Provided
    Number Of Devices: 4

Handle 0x0025, DMI type 17, 27 bytes
Memory Device
    Array Handle: 0x0024
    Error Information Handle: Not Provided
    Total Width: 64 bits
    Data Width: 64 bits
    Size: 1024 MB
    Form Factor: DIMM
    Set: None
    Locator: DIMM1
    Bank Locator:  
    Type: DDR2
    Type Detail: Synchronous
    Speed: 667 MHz
    Manufacturer: CE00000000000000
    Serial Number: 79312833
    Asset Tag: 020748
    Part Number: M3 78T2953EZ3-CE6 

Handle 0x0026, DMI type 17, 27 bytes
Memory Device
    Array Handle: 0x0024
    Error Information Handle: Not Provided
    Total Width: 64 bits
    Data Width: 64 bits
    Size: 2048 MB
    Form Factor: DIMM
    Set: None
    Locator: DIMM2
    Bank Locator:  
    Type: DDR2
    Type Detail: Synchronous
    Speed: 667 MHz
    Manufacturer: 7FBA000000000000
    Serial Number: 00000000
    Asset Tag: 000000
    Part Number:                   

Handle 0x0027, DMI type 17, 27 bytes
Memory Device
    Array Handle: 0x0024
    Error Information Handle: Not Provided
    Total Width: 64 bits
    Data Width: 64 bits
    Size: 1024 MB
    Form Factor: DIMM
    Set: None
    Locator: DIMM3
    Bank Locator:  
    Type: DDR2
    Type Detail: Synchronous
    Speed: 667 MHz
    Manufacturer: CE00000000000000
    Serial Number: 7931280C
    Asset Tag: 020748
    Part Number: M3 78T2953EZ3-CE6 

Handle 0x0028, DMI type 17, 27 bytes
Memory Device
    Array Handle: 0x0024
    Error Information Handle: Not Provided
    Total Width: 64 bits
    Data Width: 64 bits
    Size: 2048 MB
    Form Factor: DIMM
    Set: None
    Locator: DIMM4
    Bank Locator:  
    Type: DDR2
    Type Detail: Synchronous
    Speed: 667 MHz
    Manufacturer: 7FBA000000000000
    Serial Number: 00000000
    Asset Tag: 000000
    Part Number:
```

Comment: PAE is irrelevant on the 64-bit kernel. What version of Ubuntu do you have installed? Are you absolutely certain it's 64-bit or 32-bit with PAE? Include the output of `uname -a` in your question please.

Comment: I'm sure. I debated for a long time before installing. However, I definately could have messed something up.

Comment: Ubuntu 12.04 LTS

Comment: **Please edit your original question** and add the output of `uname -a` in the **question above.**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The amount you are seeing is usable. It is likely there is some reserved for video buffer.

Try

`sudo dmidecode -t memory`

see if that shows all 6

Comment: Looks like you have 6G there!

Comment: True, but this says that it doesn't matter. At least that is how I'm reading it.Handle 0x0024, DMI type 16, 15 bytes Physical Memory Array Location: System Board Or Motherboard Use: System Memory Error Correction Type: None **Maximum Capacity: 4 GB** Error Information Handle: Not Provided Number Of Devices: 4